# Not sure why this is outputting only the first column and not the whole df in R?

Tags: r, loops, nested

```
QName   Qstrt   Qend  Div
Br545    20     2300  0.002
Br345    20     2300  0.003
Br545    20     2300  0.001
Br545    20     2300  0.006
```

I have a data frame consisting of these 4 columns and a couple more. I am trying to make a criteria to compare the first value of Qname with the others in that column and if they are equal compare Qstrt and Qend. I had to use a loop in my script before and so this is contained within a nested for loop.

```
 for(i in as.matrix(d1)) {
    if(any(na.omit(d1[,"Qname"] == c(i)))) {
      print(c(i))
    }
  }
```

What I'm confused about is this loop does what it is supposed to do but when I print c(i) or print(i) it prints out only that column and not the whole data frame. I want to sort the whole frame like the output below.

Expected Output:

```
QName   Qstrt   Qend  Div
Br545    20     2300  0.002
Br545    20     2300  0.001
Br545    20     2300  0.006
```

Comment: when you do `for(i in as.matrix(d1))` you are indexing your loop in each cell of the matrix. Therefore, `i` will always be a single element, either numeric or character

Comment: Another thing, do you want to `sort` the data.frame or exclude the lines where `QName`does not match your iteration?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarenga Ohhh I see that makes more sense now, and yeah I want to eliminate the ones that do not match.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep all observations that match the first one in the data frame, there is no need to loop over it.

First find out the first observation `head(d1$QName, n = 1)`, then find the matches by subsetting the rows of the `data.frame`

```
d2 <- d1[d1$QName == head(d1$QName, n = 1),]
  QName Qstrt Qend   Div
1 Br545    20 2300 0.002
3 Br545    20 2300 0.001
4 Br545    20 2300 0.006
```